# Selected values radio_button rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, form-for

How to get the value of the selected element. And save it in a variable for display in span. I tried to save directly to the database. The database also does not save the selected value.

```
...
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons( :route_id, Route.all, :id, :time_trip, {}, {name: "timeselect", class: "timeselect"})  %>
... 
 <span id="timevalue"></span>
```

Jquery

```
(document).ready(function () {

$('input[name="timeselect"]:radio').change(function(){

        var str3="";
        $('input[name="timeselect"]:checked').val();
            str3 += $(this).text() + "\n";

        $("#timevalue").text();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the name option just to be able to select the is not a very good idea since it will effect the parameters.

In Rails when you use the form builders:

```
<%= form_for(Foo.new) %>
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons( :route_id, Route.all, :id, :time_trip, {}, { class: "timeselect" })  %>
<% end %>
```

This would give you the following params hash:

```
foo: {
  route_id: 1
}
```

The "root" key is deduced by calling `.model_name` on the model you bind to the form builder.

These params can be simply whitelisted strong parameters:

```
params.require(:foo).permit(:route_id)
```

You can select the element by:

```
$('input[name="foo[route_id]"]')
```

Or by the ID - the simplest way to check each is by either looking at the HTML output or using the browser inspector.

Comment: The database saves, but 
`$('input[name="orders[route_id]"]:radio').change(function(){

        var str3="";
       $('input[name="orders[route_id]"]:checked').val();
            str3 += $(this).text() + "\n";

        $("#timevalue").text(str3)
    });` don't worked